# SSIS Choosing Wrong Data Type

Tags: ssis, dataflowtask

I've created a table in SQL Server 2016 with this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Stage.Test (f1 DATE NULL);

INSERT INTO Stage.Test (f1) VALUES ('1/1/2000');
```

Notice the f1 column uses the DATE data type.

Then I created a data flow task in SQL Server Data Tools (VS 2019) to load data from that table.  I created an OLEDB Source Component and set the source table to Stage.Test.  But when I examine the data type of the "f1" column (in both the 'External Column' and 'Output Column' columns), it says it's a Unicode string:

[image: OLEDB source component image]

Why is it choosing a Unicode string instead of DT_DATE?

Comment: This is quite mysterious - I've never seen SSIS do this.

Comment: Yeah, neither have I.  Are you able to reproduce this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this exact example when it comes to date fields but SSIS converts data automatically when it has detected the field to be of a certain type. Perhaps it's the '/' in your date field that does it. We do not use this date format over in these parts of the world so I've never had the problem. You can especially see this when you import excel files with SSIS. I usually have this problem with strings where unicode strings can sometimes become non-unicode strings.

A way to fix could be to:

1. edit the sql query to explicitly cast the field as date
2. add a conversion step in the data flow after the source (like a derived column getting the parts of the string in the right order)
3. try to change the output datatype by right clicking on the source in the data flow and using the advanced editor and then edit the output column datatype:
   [SSIS Source Advanced Editor Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMtC9.png)

I'm not sure if that 3 would work with this date format issue as I do not have experience with the format myself but it is working fine for my unicode/non-unicode problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  My current workaround is to simply change the data type of the "f1" column in the table from DATE to DATETIME.  SSIS appears to correctly determine the right data type in this case.  Not ideal but it works.  Still like to know why it has trouble with the DATE data type.

Comment: But the data type is quite explicitly `DATE` in the table. So SSIS should reflect that. Yes you can definitely see this issue for things like text and excel because they don't have data types, and both the excel and text drivers are barely functional.